# Split string on non-alphanumeric characters and on positions between digits and non-digits

Tags: php, regex, string, split, preg-split

I'm trying to split a string by non-alphanumeric delimiting characters AND between alternations of digits and non-digits.  The end result should be a flat array of consisting of alphabetic strings and numeric strings.

I'm working in PHP, and would like to use REGEX.

Examples:

- `ES-3810/24MX` should become `['ES', '3810', '24', 'MX']`
- `CISCO1538M` should become `['CISCO' , '1538', 'M']`

The input file sequence can be indifferently DIGITS or ALPHA.

The separators can be non-ALPHA and non-DIGIT chars, as well as a change between a DIGIT sequence to an APLHA sequence, and vice versa.

Comment: The answer you accepted has a bug in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command to match all occurrances of a regex is `preg_match_all()` which outputs a multidimensional array of results. The regex is very simple... any digit (`[0-9]`) one or more times (`+`) or (`|`) any letter (`[A-z]`) one or more times (`+`). Note the capital `A` and lowercase `z` to include all upper and lowercase letters.

The textarea and php tags are inluded for convenience, so you can drop into your php file and see the results.

```
<textarea style="width:400px; height:400px;">
<?php

foreach( array(
        "ES-3810/24MX",
        "CISCO1538M",
        "123ABC-ThatsHowEasy"
    ) as $string ){

    // get all matches into an array
    preg_match_all("/[0-9]+|[[:upper:][:lower:]]+/",$string,$matches);

    // it is the 0th match that you are interested in...
    print_r( $matches[0] );

}

?>
</textarea>
```

Which outputs in the textarea:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ES
    [1] => 3810
    [2] => 24
    [3] => MX
)
Array
(
    [0] => CISCO
    [1] => 1538
    [2] => M
)
Array
(
    [0] => 123
    [1] => ABC
    [2] => ThatsHowEasy
)
```

Comment: Great ! That's good enough for me, Billy. Thanks a lot.

That was the missing part for me to create a request on a big database to search easily bad formatted products, and detect duplicated items with different formats. Very helpful.

Comment: **WRONG ANSWER** Please stop using `[A-z]`, damn it.  It has things you don’t want and doesn’t have stuff you do.  Uppercase letters are `\p{Lu}`, and lowercase letters are `\p{Ll}`.

Comment: Of course you are right, I have updated my answer, I hope you enjoy my `[[:upper:][:lower:]]` a little more than my `[A-z]`

Comment: No problem, I've only upper chars in my db. That didn't annoy me.

Comment: still, it is good for other visitors to this page to see how it can be done better. as far as I know `[:lower:]` matches accented uppercase letters as well as `a-z` in the unicode range. Therefore, it can be used to match words like `café`. It is actually quite frustrating when for example form validation does not allow for these diacriticals for no reason other than the coder thinks [a-z] covers all lowercase letters. It is something that people need to be aware of in their regex, so I don't want to contribute to the ignorance of this issue.

Comment: Why would anyone ever use `[[:lower:]]` instead of `\p{Ll}`?  It’s twice as long. Yes, technically there is a difference between `\p{Lowercase=True}` and `\p{General_Category=Lowercase_Letter}`, but I rather doubt PHP can capture that distinction.

Comment: it is `[:lower:]` not `[[:lower:]]`, so actually only 1.5 times as long. The reason I think people would use it is it is much more readable - which I think is a much underrated feature of good code.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "ES-3810/24MX35 123 TEST 34/TEST";
$str = preg_replace(array("#[^A-Z0-9]+#i","#\s+#","#([A-Z])([0-9])#i","#([0-9])([A-Z])#i"),array(" "," ","$1 $2","$1 $2"),$str);
echo $str;
$data = explode(" ",$str);
print_r($data);
```

I could not think on a more 'cleaner' way.

Comment: I do not support making for separate passes over the input string (four different patterns) to inject spaces, then exploding on spaces.  This unexplained answer is too verbose, too inefficient, and too uninspired.

Answer (score 1):

The most direct `preg_` function to produce the desired flat output array is `preg_split()`.

Because it doesn't matter what combination of alphanumeric characters are on either side of a sequence of non-alphanumeric characters, you can greedily split on non-alphanumeric substrings without "looking around".

After that preliminary obstacle is dealt with, then split on the zero-length positions between a digit and a non-digit OR between a non-digit and a digit.

```
/             #starting delimiter
[^a-z\d]+     #match one or more non-alphanumeric characters
|             #OR
\d\K(?=\D)    #match a number, then forget it, then lookahead for a non-number
|             #OR
\D\K(?=\d)    #match a non-number, then forget it, then lookahead for a number
/             #ending delimiter
i             #case-insensitive flag
```

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/B3rqQ))

```
var_export(
    preg_split('/[^a-z\d]+|\d\K(?=\D)|\D\K(?=\d)/i', $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
);
```

`preg_match_all()` isn't a silly technique, but it doesn't return the array, it returns the number of matches and generates a reference variable containing a two dimensional array of which the first element needs to be accessed. Admittedly, the pattern is shorter and easier to follow. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Jq3Sk))

```
var_export(
    preg_match_all('/[a-z]+|\d+/i', $string, $m) ? $m[0] : []
);
```